# Is it possible to install Cinnamon alongside Gnome?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, cinnamon

I have Ubuntu Jammy 22.04 installed, and I'd like to have a choice of Gnome and Cinnamon on the login screen. Is it possible to install Cinnamon this way like Icewm manager? I suppose the answer is 'No' because Cinnamon is the fork of Gnome 3 and is incompatible with gtk4. I heard that Cinnamon is about to be Ubuntu flavor so it is not offtop here.

Comment: you can install all the desktop environments. provided you have the disk space. give it a go.

Comment: I have installed it. Now there is a variety of desktop environments.

Comment: Ubuntu Cinnamon 23.04 is an *official* flavor but has not yet been released; thus is still off-topic on this site (prior releases are not retro-actively made a *flavor* still being re-spins).  Regardless if your system was Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop and you're adding a second desktop to your system - I see that as on-topic for this site regardless of Ubuntu Cinnamon being a *flavor* from 23.04 onwards (as you're using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and adding software to it!)  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue781#Ubuntu_Cinnamon_for_Official_Flavor_Status